# Perl: installing Alien::SVN fails with Base class package "Module::Build" is empty

Tags: macos, perl, homebrew, cpan

Running the command `cpan Alien::SVN` fails with the following output

```
Base class package "Module::Build" is empty.
    (Perhaps you need to 'use' the module which defines that package first,
    or make that module available in @INC (@INC contains: inc /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.24.1//lib/perl5/5.24.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.24.1/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.24.1/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.24.1/lib/perl5/5.24.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.24.1/lib/perl5/5.24.1 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.1 .).
 at inc/My/SVN/Builder.pm line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at inc/My/SVN/Builder.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at Build.PL line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Build.PL line 6.
Warning: No success on command[/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.24.1/bin/perl Build.PL]
  MSCHWERN/Alien-SVN-v1.8.11.0.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.24.1/bin/perl Build.PL -- NOT OK
```

Full output at https://gist.github.com/e072fc0785310f47c3ac1f201eb45d7b

### Environment

OS: MacOS 10.10.5
Perl: 5.24.1
Cpan: 1.6.1

Perl is installed via [homebrew](https://brew.sh).

I have also tried setting the following environment variables

```
export PERL5LIB=${PERL5LIB}:/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.24.1//lib/perl5/5.24.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level
export PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=$HOME/perl5"
```